# How to 'autocall' a method in java

Tags: java

I'm programming with Java and can't figure out how. I don't know how this is called, so I hope to get an answer by posting an example.

```
void MethodX(){
    if (A.isTrue){
        x = A.Method1);
    }else if (B.isTrue){
        x = B.Method1);
    }else if (C.isTrue){
        x = C.Method1);
    }else if (D.isTrue){
        x = D.Method1);
    }
}
```

I think there's an easier way to do this, but can't figure out how to. I don't need the exact answer, but it would be nice to have some keywords to know what to search...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this? Are this all static fields? Are ABCD instances of something?

Comment: What do you mean by autocall?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `...Method1()` (with both brackets)? Also method names are not capitalised by convention.

Comment: uooo: yes, this are all static fields. ABCD are instances of something.
Manu Viswam: i mean i want to write 1 statement that fills in "A" or "B" ect... Don't know how that is called ;p
Trengot: yes, ...method1(). thx, i won't write them with capitals..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make each of your A,B,C and D classes implement an Interface which has the `isTrue()` and `method1()` methods on it, let's call it `OurObject` for arguments sake.

Add each of the classes to a list of `OurObject` type and loop over them as so:

```
List<OurObject> ourObjectList = Arrays.asList(A,B,C,D);

for (OurObject : ourObject : ourObjectList ) {
    if (ourObject.isTrue()) {
        ourObject.method1();
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` is present so that we break out of the loop once we have found a true case. If the classes are added to the list in the order of A, B, C and then D, this will recreate the `if else if` functionality in your question.

If you want every class that returns true for the `isTrue()` method to call `method1()`, remove the `break` from the loop.

Comment: Rename OurInterface to OurObject.